# bulk media crop for featured images

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, media, plugin-recommendation, editor, bulk

I want to select all the images which are used as "featured image" on woocommerce products and modify and crop the images to fit a specific height.

Does anyone know if there is a plugin available or some trick to automate this or any other helpful suggestion.

I really do not want to spend few hours to manually modify each image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would set a your preferred featured image/thumbnail dimensions either in Settings or, if you have or need a new special image type, by adding it to your functions PHP - something like:

`add_image_size( 'product_preview', 55, 55, true ) ;`

In order to retroactively crop the old images, pretty much standard practice these days (1 million users) seems to be to use the "Regenerate Thumbnails" plug-in, which also regenerates the other image sizes. https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/